# Issue with Google Analytics tracking in Apple devices

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I am tracking my website analytics in GA. Everything is getting tracked properly till last month. But from last one month i see a drastic difference in my analytics from IOS devices. There is almost 95% drop suddenly and i am not sure what the reason is. all the other operating systems are completely fine. Its just the problem with all the browsers with IOS operating system.

Is that the problem with any GA update / is there any other problem?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to your question?  I am seeing the same kind of issue. iOS devices are not tracking properly.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer for this issue its just because of some unzipping issue with IOS devices.